# How to Derive the Edge List From Adjacency Matrix with Given Row/Col Headers

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I've written the following code. It correctly is deriving the edge list from the matrix but it is by row # and col # instead of row name and column name. My questions are (1) how can I add the row and col names to the edge list instead of the row/col numbers and (2) how can I control the edge list to be directed or undirected as options to be generated?

```
data = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
   1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}}; head = {{S0, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8}, {c1, c2, c3, c4,
    c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, c14, c15, c16}}; 
Join[Transpose[{Join[{""}, head[[1]]]}], Join[head[[{2}]], data], 
  2] // Grid
rownames = {S0, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8};
colnames = {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, 
  c14, c15, c16}; edgelist = 
 Rest[Rule @@@ SparseArray[data]["NonzeroPositions"]]
```

Comment: "I've written the following code" - did you mean to paste the code here?  You need to add an example to show what you mean.

Comment: had trouble with the code block; just re-entered the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

(1) `Apply[rownames[[#1]] -> colnames[[#2]] &, SparseArray[data]["NonzeroPositions"], {1}]`

(2) `Apply[rownames[[#1]] \[UndirectedEdge] colnames[[#2]] &, SparseArray[data]["NonzeroPositions"], {1}]`

As for directed or undirected being options, I would guess what you're wanting is to turn this into a function. It should probably take the row names and column names as arguments. Maybe something like this:

```
NamedDirectedEdges[rownames_, colnames_, edgelist_] := 
  Apply[rownames[[#1]] -> colnames[[#2]] &, edgelist, {1}];
NamedUndirectedEdges[rownames_, colnames_, edgelist_] :=
  Apply[rownames[[#1]] \[UndirectedEdge] colnames[[#2]] &, edgelist, {1}];

(*Usage: NamedDirectedEdges[rownames, colnames, SparseArray[data]["NonzeroPositions"]]*)
```

Comment: Very nice and many thanks for sharing your insights ... regards ... prg

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[toEdges]
toEdges[e : (DirectedEdge | UndirectedEdge) : DirectedEdge] := 
  MapThread[{r, c} |-> e[#2[[r]], #3[[c]]]] @ 
    Transpose[SparseArray[#]["NonzeroPositions"]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
Graph[toEdges[][data, rownames, colnames], VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
Graph[toEdges[UndirectedEdge][data, rownames, colnames], VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `data` to construct an [`AdjacencyMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyMatrix.html) and use it with [`AdjacencyGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyGraph.html) (specifying vertex names in the first argument) and extract the [`EdgeList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeList.html):

```
dam = ArrayFlatten[{{0, data}, {  0 Transpose @ data , 0}}];

del = EdgeList @ AdjacencyGraph[Join[rownames, colnames], dam];

Graph[del, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

To get an undirected graph replace `0 Transpose @ data` with `Transpose @ data`:

```
uam = ArrayFlatten[{{0, data}, {   Transpose@data , 0}}];

uel = EdgeList @ AdjacencyGraph[Join[rownames, colnames], uam];

Graph[uel, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, kglr the undirected switchover is very clever!!